# How to hash an int[] in c#

Tags: c#, .net, hash, int

I'm trying to think of a way to override GetHashCode() when called from a Vector2[]. This code produces non unique hashes for objects that I know to be equal: I pass the following class the same rectangle, and different hash codes are generated.

```
public Shape(Rectangle r)
        {
            edges = new Vector2[4];
            edges[0] = new Vector2(0, 0);
            edges[1] = new Vector2(r.Width, 0);
            edges[2] = new Vector2(r.Width, r.Height);
            edges[3] = new Vector2(0, r.Height);
            Console.Write(edges.GetHashCode() + "\n");
            Position = new Vector2(r.X, r.Y);                
        }
```

A Vector2 array is just bunch of ints. How can I create a unique hash for a list of ints?

Comment: This could should work. Can you post a complete example that shows two equal vectors producing different hash codes?

Comment: Arrays don't provide a hash code based on the content of the array.. so this code won't work. You have to roll your own, or if you're on .NET 4 use [IStructuralEquatable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.istructuralequatable.aspx).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Really? Then what does [Vector2.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.gethashcode%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx) return?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The Hash for a Vector2 instance. But `edges.GetHashCode` won't produce a hash based on each Vector2 instance in the array. Note that edges is an array of Vector2's..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Oh! Right, good catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
public static int CombineHashCodes(params int[] hashCodes)
{
    if (hashCodes == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("hashCodes");
    }

    if (hashCodes.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }

    if (hashCodes.Length == 1)
    {
        return hashCodes[0];
    }

    var result = hashCodes[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < hashCodes.Length; i++)
    {
        result = CombineHashCodes(result, hashCodes[i]);
    }

    return result;
}

private static int CombineHashCodes(int h1, int h2)
{
    return (h1 << 5) + h1 ^ h2;

    // another implementation
    //unchecked
    //{
    //    var hash = 17;

    //    hash = hash * 23 + h1;
    //    hash = hash * 23 + h2;

    //    return hash;
    //}
}
```

Comment: So, it loops through an array two ints at a time, carrying a total which is bit shifted by five each iteration, and incremented by itself ^ the next number. Maybe I don't understand how bit shifting works, but won't this produce a massive, massive number? And I should mod out by the size of my hash table at the end? Regardless, I find this helpful.

Comment: @MaxKessler No. It uses a running "barrel hash" (h1 is mixed with h2) so it never exceeds the size of an int and *bits shifted off of the end are dropped*. Remember that, generally, *hashes are not (and cannot be) unique*; they must only be stable and, hopefully, well-distributed.

Comment: Understood! I changed my code so that a collision is not used as a means of identifying whether two objects are equal: I did a little research, and overrode the equals method on my objects. Thank you very much!